# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, arm64

I have installed below mentioned pods :

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'

pod 'Firebase/Invites'

pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

After installation it is working fine on simulator and devices but while Archiving i am getting below mentioned error :
[image]

I have added $(inherited) in Other Linker Flag , and Set Build Active Architecture Only to Yes/No both ways but nothing worked.

Comment: did you find the solution. i have same problem

Comment: After trying lot, i just updated pods to the zip copy of project i had kept and everything was working fine .